# Calling native code in hybrid application built using famo.us

Tags: javascript, hybrid-mobile-app, famo.us

I'm building a mobile application that uses a third party component which is only available in native languages (Android and iOS). 
I read a lot about Famo.us and how powerful and promising it is when it comes to building hybrid mobile apps but not sure if there is a way to call the native code third party SDKs.
Your help is highly appreciated in this matter!

Comment: You need to provide more information.  Famous is only a js framework and does not call the native api's directly.  You will be using a third party wrapper and that wrapper will determine the functionality of the call.

Comment: Famo.us wrapper is still in private beta, far as I know. Within this wrapper you will probably be able to access the native SDKs. You can probably wrap famo.us with phonegap as well, but I think the famo.us wrapper will be the best choice, when it goes public. One advantage is the possible use, from what I understand, of Intel's crosswalk for android applications. Intel's crosswalk replaces the android webview with an up-to-date chromium webview.

Comment: you need to use cordova / phonegap and build a plugin to access the native code and give your javascript api points it can use.